# How to sum arithmetic combinations of divergent zeta-values?

Tags: analysis, divergent-series

By means of [Ramanujan Summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation), one can sum divergent values of the Riemann-zeta function. For instance, we have: 
$$ \zeta(-2k) = 1 + 2^{2k} + 3^{2k} + \dots = 0    ( \mathfrak{R} )  , $$ and 
$$ \zeta(-(2k - 1)) = 1 + 2^{2k-1} + 3^{2k-1} + \dots = - \frac{B_{2k} } {2k} (\mathfrak{R} ) .   $$ Another interesting result is: $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \gamma (\mathfrak{R} )  .$$

From now on, I will slighty deviate from the wikipedia notation. I will write the Ramanujan summation symbol as an operator, rather than a strange-looking letter at the end of the equation. For instance, I will write: $R( \zeta(1))= \gamma$. This will make asking the questions more convenient.

Now, to the questions. I am wondering how to sum arithmetic combinations of these sums. Let $D_1 , D_2 , \dots , D_i, \dots ,  D_n $ be divergent series that are summable by means of the Ramanujan summation method. I am wondering how to sum the following:

1. What is $R(D_1 + D_2)$ ? How does it relate to $R(D_1)$ and $R(D_2)$ ? In general: How does $R( \sum_{i \in I} D_i ) $ relate to $\cup_{i \in I} \{ R(D_i) \} $?
2. What is $R(D_1 \cdot D_2)$? How does it relate to $R(D_1)$ and $R(D_2)$? Same questions apply to summing the product of $i \in I$ divergent series.

In case it is not possible to answer these questions in general: I am also interested in particular examples. For instance, I would also be glad to know what the result of $R(\zeta(-2) + \zeta(-3))$ or $R(\zeta(-3) + \zeta(-5))$ is. I am particularly interested in finding the value of $R( (\zeta(1))^3 ) $

Answer (score 2):

This answer will go over summing divergent series generally as opposed to just the divergent zeta values, I think people stumbling on this page might find this useful. If you want to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ correctly then you need to be able to decompose $f(n)$ into its "constituent asymptotic parts" something which I don't claim to have a rigorous definition of but you'll see what I mean. For our purposes we consider $f(n)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ has monotonically increasing partial sums. We consider $g(n) = 2^n + n + 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{2^n}$  as a concrete example to following along with.

So we want to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g(n)$

$$ g(n) = \underbrace{2^n}_{\text{highly divergent}} + \underbrace{n}_{\text{medium divergent increasing}} + \underbrace{1}_{\text{medium divergent constant}} +  \underbrace{\frac{1}{n}}_{\text{medium divergent decreasing}} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2^n}}_{\text{convergent}}   $$

The *convergent* portion is easy to sum. We just sum it. The *medium divergent decreasing* is considerably trickier to sum lets call its $m(n)$ so $m(n)= \frac{1}{n}$. All medium divergent decreasing functions should have a singularity at 0, if yours doesn't then that usually means your decomposition to "asymptotic parts" was flawed in some subtle way. Ramanujan shows us that

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left[  \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} m(n) - \int_{1}^{x} m(n) dn \right] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m(n)  $$

So we conclude then that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \gamma $$

The *medium divergent constant* is a bit trickier lets call it $c(n)$. We essentially want the same Ramanujan summation procedure as before but now because we don't have a singularity at 0, our integration bounds change slightly. See below:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor} C(n) - \int_{0}^x C(n)$$

Now this function is NOT going to sum to a constant instead its going to be a wave like function that keeps alternating. To "describe" this wave as a constant we can just look at its constant term in its fourier expansion. So in our case

$$   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c(n) = \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \int_p^{p+1} \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor} c(n) - \int_{0}^x c(n) \right] dx $$

In our case this gives us

$$  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1 = \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \int_p^{p+1} \left[ \lfloor x \rfloor - x \right] dx = -\frac{1}{2} $$

The *medium divergent increasing* case is even more complex. Instead of just looking at the constant term of a limit of a fourier expansion we have to grapple with the fact that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} n - \int_{0}^{x} n dn  $$

doesn't even look periodic. What's interesting however is that

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{x} \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} n - \int_{0}^{x} n dn  \right] $$

Does look periodic in the limit. So a strategy arises, what if we divide out by x, get the fourier series of that periodic function call it $Q_0$, then subtract  $x*Q_0$ and then whatever remains MIGHT be periodic. And we go ahead and take the constant term of that periodic function. You can indeed do this to find:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} n - \int_{0}^{x} n dn = x \left(  \lfloor x \rfloor - x + \frac{1}{2} \right) + \frac{1}{2} \left( x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 - \frac{1}{8}  $$

Observe here that $\left(  \lfloor x \rfloor - x + \frac{1}{2} \right)$ is periodic so $x \left(  \lfloor x \rfloor - x + \frac{1}{2} \right)$ subtracts away our divergent jiggle and we are left with an asymptotically lower order jiggle $\frac{1}{2} \left( x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 - \frac{1}{8} $ . In our case we get lucky and this wave doesn't diverge. So that immediately leads us to the constant term of the fourier expansion of:

$$ \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \int_{p}^{p+1} \frac{1}{2} \left( x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 - \frac{1}{8} dx = -\frac{1}{12}  $$

Thus

$$ 1+ 2+ 3+ 4+ ... = -\frac{1}{12}$$

Now at some point (I don't know exactly when) Ramanujan summation stops being applicable. I believe this has a connection with the fact that $\int P(n) = O(nP(n))$ but $\int e^x = O(e^x)$ but I have nothing more than smoke and mirrors to offer there. What i do know for fact is that for sufficiently fast growing functions $h(n)$ (that I shall call *highly divergent* ) the summation procedure is to expand the sum of $h(n)$ (not its sum - integral difference) into a bunch of a periodic*(growing function) terms and just grab the constant term off of the lowest order periodic term. We see this in action below

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} 2^n = \frac{1 - 2^{\lfloor x \rfloor+1}}{1 - 2} = 2^x \left( 2^{\lfloor x \rfloor - x} \right)  -1 $$

Notice here that $\left( 2^{ \lfloor x \rfloor - x} \right) $ is a periodic function so the term $2^x \left( 2^{\lfloor x \rfloor - x} \right)$ subtracts away the highest order periodic behavior of $\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} 2^n$ in a certain sense. What's left is the periodic function $-1$ whose constant fourier coefficient trivially is $-1$ thus we conclude that

$$ 1+ 2 + 4 +8 + ... = -1$$

So to recap, the name of the game is to "split your function being summed into its constituent asymptotic parts", then for each part use the correct summation procedure. The summation procedures themselves up to some careful bounds generally consist of "subtracting off" higher order wave-like terms to reveal asymptotically lower order wave-like terms, and in doing this reductions enough leave you with a final bounded wave-like term -- The constant term of this is the sum of your divergent sum.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: The $R$ operator is linear, so $R(\sum_{i\in I} D_i)=\sum_{i\in I} R(D_i)$ at least for finite $I$.

Comment: How do you know the $R$ operator is linear?

Comment: @Max: perhaps this small treatize on the representation of the Euler-MacLaurin-formula in terms of a matrix-operation might be interesting, because the Euler-MacLaurin-formula is at the heart of the Ramanujan-summation. *(Having this in a matrix form one might say that the "Ramanujan-summation is a linear operator" .)* see: http://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial_new/EulerMacLaurin.pdf