# What is the periodic function that $\frac{\ln\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} n! \right) - x \ln(x) + x }{\ln(x)}$ converges to?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, experimental-mathematics

I was analyzing the function

$$\frac{\ln \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} n! \right) - x \ln(x) + x}{\ln(x)}  $$

I had a hunch that this object tends to a periodic function as $x \rightarrow \infty$  (which generalizes some ideas to an answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377294/how-to-sum-arithmetic-combinations-of-divergent-zeta-values/4730581#4730581)) but I'm having difficulty determining what that actual function should be.

If one just goes ahead and graphs [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dma67poxc8) on Desmos:

[image]

Then its easy to see that this very closely resembles something of the form $c - \lbrace x\rbrace$ where $\lbrace x \rbrace$ is the fractional part function and $c$ is some unknown constant.

Now Unfortunately Desmos fails to graph this beyond $x = 170$ most likely due to arithmetic limits and even with Wolfram Mathematica evaluated around $x=3000$ this graph still seems to have some small offset $C > \frac{1}{2}$. In my experience constants like this usually are nice numbers like $\frac{1}{2}$ so this might be because I need to go to something much larger like $x=10^{100}$ to notice it. But its just as plausible that it might genuinely be some weird magic constant thats close to but not exactly $\frac{1}{2}$.

[image]

So at this point I believe the periodic limiting function (lets call it $P(x)$  looks like

$$ P(x) = C - \lbrace x\rbrace + a_2  \lbrace x\rbrace ^2 + a_3 \lbrace x\rbrace ^3 ... $$

Where the higher order $a_2, a_3.... $ if they exist must be truly miniscule.

Is it possible to calculate what that $C$ and higher order terms will be in a closed form, or even numerically, but if numerically then in a way thats 100% certain about the digits it has extracted? My strategy of just scrolling to the right and reading the digits is definitely very poor way to do this.

### Attempts to Derive:

In similar problems I often try to use the Euler Maclaurin formula so we can attempt to do that here

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} n! = \int_{0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} n! dn + \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor ! - 0!}{2} + \frac{1}{12} \left( \frac{d}{dn} \left[ n! \right]  \right)|_{0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} + ... $$

Now considering that from Stirlings formula we have that $n! \sim e^{n \ln(n) - n + 1/2 \ln(2\pi n)  }$ it's clear that the integral term will be of lower order compared to the derivative terms. But quickly this formula turns into a mess when you make such simplifications and that doesn't seem to get me closer to understanding the desired asymptotics.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Oh more than well! I am sorry for the delay in accepting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Note that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/278498)
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } {n!}  = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor !\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right)
$$
as $x\to+\infty$. Hence, by Stirling's formula,
\begin{align*}
\ln \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } {n!} } \right)& = \ln (\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor !) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right) = \left( {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\ln \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \ln \sqrt {2\pi }  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)
\\ & = \left(\frac{1}{2}- \left\{ x \right\}\right)\ln x + x\ln x - x  + \ln \sqrt {2\pi }  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)
\end{align*}
as $x\to+\infty$, with $\left\{ x \right\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$. Consequently, your function is
$$
\frac{1}{2} - \left\{ x \right\}+ \frac{{\ln \sqrt {2\pi } }}{{\ln x}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x\ln x}}} \right)
$$
as $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: This was really brilliant and succinct. Thank you! I was able to use this on some other series as well such as $n^n$